# Better way to terminate / stop / kill Spark jobs from a Play Framework controller using an API?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework

I do have a controller named `SparkJobController`

```
class SparkJobController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {
  val jobsMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, SparkAppHandle]

  /* POST request that takes ID to pass to the spark-submit (to be) jar */
  def run: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { request =>
    request.body.asJson.map { json =>
      Json.fromJson[String](json).asOpt match {
        case Some(id) =>
          val job = new SparkLauncher()
            .setSparkHome("/usr/local/spark")
            .setMaster("local[*]")
            .setAppName("spark-app")
            .setAppResource("/usr/abc/spark.jar")
            .setMainClass("example.job.MainClass")
            .addAppArgs(id)

          val jobHandle = job.startApplication()

          jobsMap += (appId -> jobHandle)
          Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(appId)))
        case None =>
          Future.successful(BadRequest)
      }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
  }

  /* POST request to kill a job taking ID returned by run API */
  def stop: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { request =>
    request.body.asJson.map { json =>
      Json.fromJson[String](json).asOpt match {
        case Some(appId) =>
          jobsMap.get(appId).map { job =>
            job.kill()
            Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(s"Successfully stopped application with appId = $appId.")))
          }.getOrElse(Future.successful(NotFound(Json.toJson("Couldn't find in queue."))))
        case None =>
          Future.successful(BadRequest)
      }
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
  }
}
```

I want to persist the `jobsMap` in database or in the cache somewhere (`Redis` may be). How can I do that? Or if not, what should I do to make a queuing system that gets job requests from API (run) and provides an API (stop) to stop/kill/terminate running jobs.

What is the most graceful way to do this?

FYI,

- Spark version is `2.3.1`
- Play version is `2.6.13`
- Scala version is `2.11.11`

Comment: Did you consider using https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis?

Comment: That's cool. I am checking it out.